# convert pubDate to timestamp rss in yql

Tags: rss, yql, pubdate

I have a YQL query where I am accessing data from an RSS feed. I want to get the pubDate for the articles in the feed, but I don't want it to be in (for example) this format:

Fri, 30 Nov 2012 14:19:55 +0000

I would prefer it to be in this format:

11/30/2012

Is there a simple function within YQL itself that would let me do this? Just to be clear, I would prefer to have a YQL-only solution, without having to use PHP or javascript or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-javascript-objects.html#yql-execute-date) link. In particular look at **y.date.getOffsetFromEpochInMillis(time_format)** function. This gives you the epoch in milliseconds.

After you get that, inside your YQL open data table definition, massage this timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy format as listed in the question [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)